# Java applying filters on nested arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, filter

I'm a beginner developer currently working in a startup as an intern, I have inherited the work of other developers, also interns, and I'm working on a web app.
The backend is in Java, I had never seen Java code before starting the internship 2 weeks ago, and therefore I have a lot of trouble reading and understanding the code sometimes, I have been stuck on this for the past 48 hours.

I have to make a function that filters profiles using a number of parmeters. Here's the function :

```
// Apply filters on our experts list
private List<UserExpertInfo> applyFilterOnUserExpertInfo(List<UserExpertInfo> experts, FiltersExpertsRequest filters) {

    if (filters.isAvailable != null && filters.isAvailable == true ) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> e.availability == false);
    }
    if (filters.name != null && !filters.name.equals("")) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> !(e.firstName + e.LastName).contains(filters.name));
    }
    if (filters.maximumPrice != null) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> !(filters.maximumPrice.longValue() >= e.wage.longValue()));
    }

    //  /!\ CAREFUL /!\ We can't have a NULL field in DB, or the removeIf function automatically returns NULL and the server sends back an error
    if (filters.minimumRating != null) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> !(filters.minimumRating.longValue() <= e.rating.longValue()));
    }

    // Expertises
    if (filters.fluids != null && filters.fluids == true) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> !e.expertises.fluids);
    }
    if (filters.thermic != null && filters.thermic == true) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> !e.expertises.thermic);
    }
    if (filters.struct != null && filters.struct == true) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> !e.expertises.struct);
    }
    if (filters.electro != null && filters.electro == true) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> !e.expertises.electroMag);
    }
   
    // Areas
    if (filters.aerospace != null && filters.aerospace == true) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.asList(e.areas).contains("AEROSPACE"));
    }
    if (filters.industries != null && filters.industries == true) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.asList(e.areas).contains("INDUSTRIES"));
    }
    if (filters.transport != null && filters.transport == true) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.asList(e.areas).contains("TRANSPORT"));
    }
    if (filters.energy != null && filters.energy == true) {
        experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.asList(e.areas).contains("ENERGY"));
    }

    // Languages : TODO
    if (filters.languages != null) {

        if (filters.languages.contains("english")) {
            experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.asList(e.languages).contains("english"));
        }
        if (filters.languages.contains("spanish")) {
            experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.asList(e.languages).contains("spanish"));
        }
        if (filters.languages.contains("french")) {
            experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.asList(e.languages).contains("french"));
        }
        if (filters.languages.contains("german")) {
            experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.asList(e.languages).contains("german"));
        }
        if (filters.languages.contains("italian")) {
            experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.asList(e.languages).contains("italian"));
        }
        if (filters.languages.contains("dutch")) {
            experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.asList(e.languages).contains("dutch"));
        }
    }

    
    // Softwares : TODO 
    
    return experts;
}
```

So, everything works pretty well, but i'm stuck at the Languages part. I can't seem to access the "name" field inside the "languages" array. Again pardon me if I misunderstand how Java works.
Here are the files on which this function relies on :

```
package fr.squad.zel.api;

import java.util.UUID;

public class UserExpertInfo {
    public UUID userId;
    public UUID expertId;
    public String title;
    public Number rating;
    public Number wage;
    public boolean availability;
    public UUID photoUrl;
    public String firstName;
    public String LastName;
    public Expertise expertises;
    public String[] areas;
    public RefSoftwares[] softwares;
    public RefLanguages[] languages;
}
```

And

```
package fr.squad.zel.api;

import java.util.UUID;

public class RefLanguages {
    public UUID id;
    public String name;

}
```

And finally here is how I get my experts param (this is only the relevant part of the function) :

```
// Get expert's areas.
        List<String> tempStringList = compoExpertsAreasServiceActions.findNamesByIdExpert(userTemp.getId());
        userExpertTemp.areas = tempStringList.toArray(new String[tempStringList.size()]);

        // Get expert's Softwares. 
        List<RefSoftwares> tempSoftwaresList = compoExpertsSoftwaresService.findAllByExpertId(userTemp.getId());
        userExpertTemp.softwares = tempSoftwaresList.toArray(new RefSoftwares[tempSoftwaresList.size()]);

        // Get expert's Languages.
        List<RefLanguages> tempLanguagesList = this.languageService.findAllByUserId(userTemp.getId());
        userExpertTemp.languages = tempLanguagesList.toArray(new RefLanguages[tempLanguagesList.size()]);

        return userExpertTemp;
```

The filters work fine, I have printed all of them. But I can't access the names of those languages, I really can't seem to grasp my head around the way those object work with eachother, and after a long time searching StackOverflow and other places, I really haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this:

```java
        if (filters.languages.contains("english")) {
            experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.asList(e.languages).contains("english"));
        }
```

Inside the lambda, `e.languages` is a `RefLanguages[]`. You can access any of the individual elements by its index, then use the field `name`, eg `e.languages[0].name`. So you could write a loop to check for your thing. You can also use the stream api, eg replacing `!Arrays.asList(e.languages).contains("italian")` with `Arrays.stream(e.languages).map(l -> l.name).noneMatch("italian"::equals)`

But your code seems to say, if `filters.languages` is not null, then only keep the experts that speak *all* the languages.

So possibly, instead of duplicating the check for every language, you can put every language name into a set and test for inclusion:

```java
experts.removeIf(e -> !Arrays.stream(e.languages)
                             .map(l -> l.name)
                             .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                             .containsAll(filters.languages));
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer ! So my code says : "Remove the expert from the list if he doesn't speak X language". 
For some reason I couldn't make languages.stream() work, but I managed to find this solution : 

`if (filters.languages.contains("french")) {
                experts.removeIf(e -> !Stream.of(e.languages).anyMatch(x -> x.name.contains("french")));
            }`

So thanks a lot man I got i to work that way !

Comment: Uh ok. `!stream.anyMatch(...)` can be replaced by `stream.noneMatch(...)` though

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a few weeks, but for future reference, I looked back at your response and got it to work using your solution (So using stream>map>collect>containsAll). So thanks again !